# Entity Framework 5 and above and DB Context best practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm setting up a brand new MVC 4.5 web project; I'm wondering how the sql connection is handled with Entity Framework 5 and above (if a new connection is opened - which is the time consuming part of dealing with the database, or if the connection remains open with the database or...)

**Please note following is NOT a real sample** of my code; it's just there to demo how I'm planning to reuse the DB Context:

**My Question**:
What's the best way of handling the repetitive part of declaring the DBContext:

> ```
> using (var dbc = new Lib.User.DAL.UserEntity())
> {
>       ...
> }
> ```

```
    public class User
    {
        public static string GetUserName(int userid)
        {
            using (var dbc = new Lib.User.DAL.UserEntity())**
            {
                var user = (from u in dbc.User where u.UserID == userid select u).FirstOrDefault();
                return user.username;
            }
        }

        public static string GetFirstName(int userID)
        {
            using (var dbc = new Lib.User.DAL.UserEntity())
            {
                var user = (from u in dbc.User where u.UserID == userID select u).FirstOrDefault();
                return user.fName;
            }

        }
    }


public class UserGroup
{
    public static string GetGroupName(int userGroupID)
    {
        using (var dbc = new Lib.User.DAL.UserEntity())
        {
            var group = (from u in dbc.UserGroup where u.UserGroupID == userGroupID select u).FirstOrDefault();
            return group.userGroupName;
        }
    }

    public static string GetAccessTypeName(int accessTypeID)
    {
        using (var dbc = new Lib.User.DAL.UserEntity())
        {
            var ga = (from u in dbc.UserGroupAccess where u.UserGroupAccessTypeID == accessTypeID select u).FirstOrDefault();
            return ga.UserGroupAccessType.accessTypeName;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: inject it as a dependency in the class it will be used

Comment: Oh I've heard of that: unity and dependency injections, etc; I'm gonna google it around unless you can find a link before I can :) thanks